# How to achieve precise audio file play durations with Exoplayer2?

Tags: android, audio, exoplayer

I am using Exoplayer2 to play an audio file in a loop. The audio file is 3600ms in length. However, different loops are played with slightly varied durations of 3811ms, 3611ms, 3589ms, 3605ms, 3602ms, 3595ms, etc. I want this to be precisely 3600ms. How do I achieve this?

I am recording the time durations in onPositionDiscontinuity with `Player.DISCONTINUITY_REASON_PERIOD_TRANSITION`.

I create Exoplayer MediaSource using `SingleSampleMediaSource.Factory`.

Could it be due to Exoplayer2's attempt to play gapless playback? If so, how do I turn gapless off.